HttpResponseMessage ReadAsStringAsync - ObjectDisposed_Generic exception
Using .NET MAUI on Android, Http requests fail every so often (the same call is successful most of the time), I can't figure out why.
It happens on various endpoints.
This is the exception:
{"HttpRequestError":0,
"Message":"net_http_content_stream_copy_error",
"Data": null,
"InnerException":{
"ClassName":"System.ObjectDisposedException",
"Message":"ObjectDisposed_Generic",
"Data":null,
"InnerException":null,
"HelpURL":null,
"StackTraceString":"   
    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf(IJavaPeerable )\n   
    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualInt32Method(String , IJavaPeerable , JniArgumentValue* )\n   
    at Java.IO.InputStream.Read(Byte[] , Int32 , Int32 )\n   at Android.Runtime.InputStreamInvoker.Read(Byte[] , Int32 , Int32 )\n   
    at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginReadInternal>b__38_0(Object <p0>)\n   
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].InnerInvoke()\n   
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__281_0(Object obj)\n   
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread , ExecutionContext , ContextCallback , Object )\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\n   
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread , ExecutionContext , ContextCallback , Object )\n   
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& , Thread )\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\n   
    at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsync>g__Core|27_0(Stream , Stream , Int32 , CancellationToken )\n   
    at System.IO.BufferedStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream , Int32 , CancellationToken )\n   
    at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.<CopyAsync>g__DisposeSourceAsync|1_0(Task , Stream )\n   
    at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task , MemoryStream )",
"RemoteStackTraceString":null,
"RemoteStackIndex":0,
"ExceptionMethod":null,
"HResult":-2146232798,
"Source":"Java.Interop",
"WatsonBuckets":null,
"ObjectName":"Java.IO.InputStreamInvoker"},
"Source":"System.Net.Http","HResult":-2146232798,"StackTrace":"   
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task , MemoryStream )\n   
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage , HttpCompletionOption , CancellationTokenSource , Boolean , CancellationTokenSource , CancellationToken )\n   
at MDC_Room.Services.ApiService.<GetRequestAync>d__5`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MDC_Room.Model.DailyReport.ChildDailyReportListItemDto, MDC_Room, Version=6.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()"}

The service making the API call is a singleton (though it uses IServiceProvider to get its IHttpClientFactor instance):
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IApiService, ApiService>();
public async Task<T?> GetRequestAync<T>(string url)
{
    try
    {
        if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            var httpClientFactory = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

            using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(AppConstants.HttpClient);

            using var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T?>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            else
                await ErrorUtility.HandleErrorAsync(response, url);
        }
        else
            await SnackbarUtility.ShowErrorSnackbarAsync("No Internet Connection", "Ok", null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorUtility.LogError(ex, $"{nameof(ApiService)}.{nameof(GetRequestAync)}");
    }
    return default;
}

The only other thing in play is a delegation handler to inject token into response:
    public class AuthenticationDelegatingHandler(IApiService _dataService) : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private const string TokenScheme = "Bearer";

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(TokenScheme, AppUtility.AccessToken ?? await TokenUtility.GetAccessTokenAsync());

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
               var user = await RefreshTokenRequiredAsync(_dataService);

                if (user == null)
                    return response;

                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(TokenScheme, user.AccessToken);
                response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }

            return response;
        }
        private static async Task<LoginResponseModel?> RefreshTokenRequiredAsync(IApiService _dataService)
        {
            var refreshToken = await TokenUtility.GetRefreshTokenAsync();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(refreshToken))
            {
                var input = new RefreshTokenDto
                {
                    Token = refreshToken
                };
                var user = await _dataService.PostRequestAync<LoginResponseModel?>(ApiEndPoints.Auth.RefreshToken, input);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SecureStorage.SetAsync(CacheKeys.User, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
                    await SecureStorage.SetAsync(CacheKeys.AccessToken, user.AccessToken!);
                    await SecureStorage.SetAsync(CacheKeys.RefreshToken, user.RefreshToken);

                    AppShellEventUtility.SetUser(user);
                }
                return user;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}

and I am using Polly to retry:
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(AppConstants.HttpClient,
client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("dotnet-docs");
})
.AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthenticationDelegatingHandler>()
.AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy);


private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy(HttpRequestMessage httpContext)
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout)
        .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
        .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
        .Or<WebException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            retryCount: 3,
            sleepDurationProvider: GetRetryDelay);
}

private static TimeSpan GetRetryDelay(int retryAttempt)
{
    return retryAttempt switch
    {
        1 => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50),
        2 => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
        _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250),
    };
}

I've looked at the following posts and ensured my using statements are placed correctly and I believe that I am returning a DTO as recommended.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException Error while copying content to a stream
Web Api Request Throws "Error while copying content to a stream."
I'm not sure what I'm missing here, any help/recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Did you test on iOS or windows to check if the problem will happen or not?

Unfortunately I don't have that option. I dont have access to a Mac to build it and I use some Android specific settings that makes my app incompatible with windows. I thought maybe I have a bug in my architecture or setup....

You can try to refer to this case: C# - Error while copying content to a stream.

I am using Polly to retry .. but I think my try/catch is triggering b/c the API response returns a success (also see that in Application Insights)  but fails when I attempt to read the data via await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), it throws the above exception. And if the try/catch is triggering, it makes me think Polly is not catching it or has already tried 3 times.

Did you try to debug to check the content? And you can try to add { } to contain the code after the using.

I did debug the content and found no issues ... a second later the same call works ... now I'm wondering if a weak connection could be related to this issue. Also will try adding braces to USING. thank you for taking the time!

Because your problem appears randomly and can't be reproduced, I can't make sure what is cause.

We are seeing the same thing occasionally on our MAUI app.  It only happens on Android and I believe it is related to the following open bug.
https://github.com/dotnet/android/issues/9039
